# Two plots 1 figure Y-scale

Tags: r, plot

I have the next issue:

I am working with matches of volleyball. So, I have the points of each team in one set. Thus, I plot the points from one team in one figure, and in other figure, the points of the remain team is plotted.

Now, I want to plot in 1 figure those 2 first plots, making a comparative. While the x-axis is the same for the two teams, the y-axis changes as is obvious, because there is a team that achieves more points.

Dataset example:
(number_of_play,point)

Team A: (1,0), (2,1), (3,2), (4,3) , (5,4).....

Team B: (1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (4,1) , (5,1) .....

Comment: Post example dataset ("I am working with matches of volleyball" doesn't help).

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Dataset example:
(number_of_play,point)

Team A: (1,0), (2,1), (3,2), (4,3) , (5,4).....


Team B: (1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (4,1) , (5,1) .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ggplot2`, just format your data before (I use `melt` function from `rehsape2` package here):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

df = data.frame(set=1:5,A=0:4,B=rep(1,5))
df1 = melt(df, id.vars='set', variable.name='team')

ggplot(df1, aes(x=set, y=value, color=team)) + geom_line()
```

[image]